# App works in simulator but not on device

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

My app runs fine on simulator but when I run on device it hangs on the first view. It doesn't call anything in viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear.  Running swift 3, iOS 10, device is a 6S updated to iOS 10.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import SwiftKeychainWrapper

class FirstVC: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    // MARK: Checks if you have an account and never logged out
    if let userId = KeychainWrapper.defaultKeychainWrapper().stringForKey(KEY_UID) {
        DataService.ds.REF_USERS.child(userId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (FIRDataSnapshot) in
            guard let dict = FIRDataSnapshot.value as? NSDictionary, let setup = dict["setup"] as? Bool else {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "firstToDemo", sender: nil)
                return
            }
            if setup {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "firstToPollBar", sender: nil)
            } else {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "firstToDemo", sender: nil)
            }
        })
    } else {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "firstToLogin", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Edit scheme, change Debug to Release to test it.

Comment: Thanks @季亨达 that worked!